# Código no ejecuta

Tags: python

necesito saber porque este codigo no ejecuta.

```
z=0 valor=0.0 n=0 cont_1=0 cont_2=0 print("Este programa cacula una secuencia matemática para un número cualquiera en un intervalo y da como resultado el intervalo y la secuencia más larga") k=int(input("Ingrese lím inferior")) z=int(input("Ingrese lím superior")) valor=0 if ( k<1000000 and z<1000000):
cont_2=0
n=k
while( n <= z):
    valor= n
    while(valor >= 1):
        if(n%2==0):
            valor= valor/2
        else:
            valor= (valor*3)+1
        cont_1+=1
    if(cont_2<cont_1):
        cont_2=cont_1
    n=k+1 print(k,z,cont_2)
```

La secuencia debe ser para cada numero del intervalo que da el usuario, la secuencia es si es un par se divide un dos y si no se multiplique *3 y se sume 1
Por cada numero del intervalo debe hacer la secuencia e imprimir la secuencia mas larga y los extremos del intervalo

Comment: Hola Fil, te damos la bienvenida a [es.so]. Sería conveniente que intentaras formatear el código de la pregunta para que se vea exactamente como lo tienes tú, con los mismo niveles de identación. en Python la identación es crucial y una línea con un nivel más o menos lo cambia todo. ¿Con no ejecuta a que te refieres? ¿Lanza alguna excepción?¿Se queda eternamente en ejecución sin mostrar nada?¿Termina pero aparentemente no hace ni muestra nada?

Comment: Probando el código he visto varias cosas, primero pasarle el "int(input, todo junto en una sola linea fallaba. Luego fallaba el naming y orden de pasar el int después del input, y un nivel de indentación en mitad. Ordenado ahora ejecuta. Y el naming deja que desear.., hay que mejorar esas buenas prácticas (naming y orden) Mr. Fil

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, el problema radica en la organización. Python es un lenguaje que requiere de indentación y cierta organización, si no falla el código.

A juzgar por el código tiene pinta de estar "copiad/pegado" de alguna parte y no comprobado del todo.

Te sugiero organizarlo mejor para evitar estos errores pues basicamente es algo de organización y un nombrado adecuado, así te será mas facil desarrollarlo.

Puedes comprobar el código en este enlace web online
[Editor python online](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

```
# coding: utf-8
# Your code here!

z=0 
valor=0.0 
n=0 
cont_1=0 
cont_2=0 


print("Este programa cacula una secuencia matemática para un número cualquiera en un intervalo y da como resultado el intervalo y la secuencia más larga")


k=input("Ingrese lím inferior")
intK=int(k)


z=input("Ingrese lím superior")
intZ=int(z)



valor=0

if ( intK<1000000 and intZ<1000000):
    cont_2= 0

n=intK
while( n <= intZ):
    valor=n
    while(valor >= 1):
        if(n%2==0):
            valor= valor/2
        else:
            valor= (valor*3)+1
        cont_1+=1
    if(cont_2<cont_1):
        cont_2=cont_1
    n=intK + 1
    print(intK,intZ,cont_2)
```

He renombrado la variable "k" por "intK" tras pasarle el int(), e igual para la "Z"

Espero que te ayude, saludos!